# How does apple group crash reports?

Tags: iphone, ios

I have received crash reports from iTunes connect. In "Most Frequent Crashes" table, there are several entities. I am wondering how apple classify several crash reports into one entity? Same reason? Can I assume they are the same root cause? And what does the hex number beside the app name stand for, e.g. 0xe7f96?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The algorithm Apple uses to group crashes is not public, so all you might get is speculation.

You cannot assume that crashes in one "group" have the same rout cause, e.g. if your app crashes because of memory leaks, you could have multiple in your app that could cause the app to crash at the same point. So it depends on the type of crash.

To understand the data that is shown in a crash report, read this [Technical Note TN2123: CrashReporter](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2004/tn2123.html) from Apple.

> [The hex number] is the program counter address within the frame of the
>   stack trace. For frame 0 this is typically the address of the
>   instruction that caused the exception. For higher frames this is the
>   return address for that frame. That is, for frame N it points to the
>   next instruction that will execute when the function referenced by
>   frame N - 1 returns.

Comment: tn2123 link is down :(

Comment: A simple search on the page for TN2123 shows the new link as the first result. Updated the link here, but that shouldn't have been too hard to find anyway.